# Vimeo - Embedded Video Is Cut Off In Internet Explorer

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm embedding videos on one of my websites and when viewed through Internet Explorer it seems as though the video is larger than it is set for, but the player window stays the same and only shows like the upper left quarter of the video with the majority of the rest of the video being "behind" the rest of the HTML, as it were. In a perfect world I'd just tell people to get a REAL browser instead of using internet explorer, but you really can't tell that to paying customers who are technologically challenged. So what's going on here? How do I correct this?

Here's the link to the forum post that I created on Vimeo.com

https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:115630

Comment: I updated the thread on https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:115630